# C/C++ resolving docker compose services to same IP

Tags: c++, docker, sockets, docker-compose, dns

I'm trying to resolve the IP addresses of some docker compose services from another container within the docker compose network running a C/C++ socket program.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    grad_calc_1:
        image: worker:1
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        environment:
            - seed=10
    grad_calc_2:
        image: worker:1
        ports: 
            - "8081:8080"
        environment:
            - seed=20
    optimizer:
        image: optimizer:1
        depends_on: 
            - grad_calc_1
            - grad_calc_2
```

Here is my code resolving the hostnames from the `optimizer` service

```
char* resolve_host(const char* host_name) {
    struct hostent *host_entry;
    char *IPbuffer;

    host_entry = gethostbyname(host_name);
    IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));    
    return IPbuffer;
}

int main() {
    const char* hostname_1 = "grad_calc_1";
    const char* hostname_2 = "grad_calc_2";

    char* ip_1 = resolve_host(hostname_1);
    char* ip_2 = resolve_host(hostname_2);
    cout << "grad_calc_1 IP: " << ip_1 << endl; 
    cout << "grad_calc_2 IP: " << ip_2 << endl;
}
```

The output is `172.19.0.2` for both hostnames. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `inet_ntoa` returns a statically allocated string, see [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa)

Comment: so that string isn't being updated by the second function invocation?

Comment: The same buffer is overwritten by that second invocation.  So you print the same value out twice.

Comment: You should probably use `inet_ntop()` instead, which understands IPv6 addresses and requires you to supply your own buffer (and therefore won't have this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @KamilCuk's comment, here's one possible fix:

```
#include <string>

std::string resolve_host(const char* host_name) {
    struct hostent *host_entry;
    const char *IPbuffer;

    host_entry = gethostbyname(host_name);
    IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));    
    return IPbuffer;
}

int main() {
    const char* hostname_1 = "grad_calc_1";
    const char* hostname_2 = "grad_calc_2";

    std::string ip_1 = resolve_host(hostname_1);
    std::string ip_2 = resolve_host(hostname_2);
    cout << "grad_calc_1 IP: " << ip_1 << endl; 
    cout << "grad_calc_2 IP: " << ip_2 << endl;
}
```

The point here is that you copy the static buffer returned by `inet_ntoa` before the next call overwrites it.

Answer (score 1):

`inet_ntoa` returns a pointer to statically allocated string. Both pointers `ip_1` and `ip_2` **point** to the same memory. Either copy the memory or use one at a time. The behavior is documented.

```
char* ip_1 = resolve_host(hostname_1);
cout << "grad_calc_1 IP: " << ip_1 << endl; 
char* ip_2 = resolve_host(hostname_2);
cout << "grad_calc_2 IP: " << ip_2 << endl;
```

or like

```
std::string ip_1{resolve_host(hostname_1)};
char* ip_2 = resolve_host(hostname_2);
cout << "grad_calc_1 IP: " << ip_1 << endl; 
cout << "grad_calc_2 IP: " << ip_2 << endl;
```